# this query taking long time to execute in sql server manegment studio 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, query-performance

```
SELECT s.option_code,s.seasonal_template_id,s.T900,s.T901,s.creator_id,s.creator_date,s.revisor_id,s.revisor_date,s.costing_sr_no,s.[T902],s.[T903]
FROM   [dbo].[tna870_seasonal_bulk_option_code_details_vendor_temp] s
   INNER JOIN mst703_master_field_values S5 
   ON S5.field_value_id = s.T900
      AND S5.field_id = (select s1.field_id from mst703_master_field s1 
                         where s1.field_code='t900')

WHERE s.seasonal_template_id = 35

AND ( s.option_code+CAST(s.seasonal_template_id AS VARCHAR(20))+s.costing_sr_no 
  NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT s2.option_code+CAST(s2.seasonal_template_id AS VARCHAR(20))+s2.costing_sr_no 
          FROM tna870_seasonal_bulk_option_code_details_vendor s2
          WHERE s2.seasonal_template_id = 35) )
```

Comment: Do you have any indices setup on these tables?

Comment: yes this table have mst703_master_field_values indice setup

Comment: what do you mean by "long time"? as compared to what? How much data do these tables have? Are you connected locally or remotely?

Comment: put some Windex on it. If that doesn't work, try to sacrifice a goat. If even that doesn't work, perhaps you should take a look at the query plan.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
SELECT
s.option_code,
s.seasonal_template_id,
s.T900,
s.T901,
s.creator_id,
s.creator_date,
s.revisor_id,
s.revisor_date,
s.costing_sr_no,
s.[T902],
s.[T903]
FROM
(
    SELECT
    *
    FROM [dbo].[tna870_seasonal_bulk_option_code_details_vendor_temp] s
    WHERE s.seasonal_template_id = 35
    AND NOT EXISTS(
                   SELECT 1 
                   FROM  tna870_seasonal_bulk_option_code_details_vendor s2 
                   WHERE s2.seasonal_template_id = s.seasonal_template_id
                   AND s2.option_code+CAST(s2.seasonal_template_id AS VARCHAR(20))+s2.costing_sr_no = s.option_code+CAST(s.seasonal_template_id AS VARCHAR(20))+s.costing_sr_no
                  )
) s
INNER JOIN mst703_master_field_values S5 
   ON S5.field_value_id = s.T900
      AND S5.field_id = (select s1.field_id from mst703_master_field s1 
                         where s1.field_code='t900')
```

Comment: thank you so much Tien Nguyen for response it works better now

Comment: It's helpful for you, you don't forget award.